# Transformando todas as variáveis em variáveis globais

Tags: php, variáveis-globais

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto e o mesmo trabalha com muitos arquivos e esses arquivos são chamados via `require_once()`.

É um trabalho árduo declarar cada variável criada como variável global tendo em vista a quantidade de arquivos, obviamente não é exatamente todas, mas as que preciso declarar necessita de atenção, pois as vezes acabo esquecendo e da erro de variável indefinida.

Fiz um teste aqui e consegui com a função nativa do PHP `get_defined_vars()`, transformar todas as variáveis em variareis globais de forma automática. O código pra isso é o seguinte:

```
foreach (get_defined_vars() as $name_var => $content_var)
{
    $GLOBALS[$name_var] = $content_var;
}
```

Facilitou o processo, pois agora consigo ter um retorno de todas as variáveis do sistema com um simples `var_dump($GLOBALS)`.

Mas mesmo isso funcionando considero uma gambiarra, pois esse método pode gerar problemas com as variáveis já que as variáveis de mesmo nome serão substituídas.

Também me preocupo com a sobrecarga de informações já que do modo que executei a função todas as variáveis, sem exceção, será uma global, sendo assim mesmo as variáveis que já não tem mais utilidade no processamento será transformada em global.

> Há alguma maneira de melhorar esse processo, fazendo a mesma coisa que quero fazer só que de um modo mais viável?

Pensei em utilizar uma classe que ficaria incumbida desse processo, onde eu poderia setar as variáveis que desejo ter acesso global. Dessa forma centralizo todas as conversões.

Comment: Por quê, exatamente, precisa das variáveis globais? Eu, particularmente, nunca vi uma aplicação que realmente precisasse fazer algo assim, então poderia explicar melhor o que está fazendo para termos certeza se é ou não um problema XY?

Comment: Digamos que eu tenho a home.view.php, pra essa view eu tenho um home.controller.php, dentro desse controlador tenho variáveis declaradas (não por funções ou classes) que possuem valores aos quais eu poderia usar no home.view, porém se eu tentar  usar qualquer uma dessas variáveis, a mesma dará erro de variável indefinida. 
Dai minha necessidade de obter essas variáveis de forma prática.

De fato o problema pode ser XY, por essa razao recorri ao site, pra vê a maneira correta de se fazer isso utilizando boas práticas, e não uma gambiarra como era isso (já mudei pra class).